# AND vs SUB when converting lowercase to uppercase in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, ascii, subtraction, instruction-set

I was wondering why you would use the `and` instruction instead of the `sub` instruction when converting lowercase ASCII characters to uppercase ones.

```
mov dx, 'a'
sub dx, 32
```

vs

```
mov dx, 'a'
and dx, 11011111b
```

Comment: It doesn't really matter if you already established that input is lower case so you know bit #5 is set. You can clear it by subtracting or masking as you like. But if the input can be upper case already, the `and` would leave it unchanged while the `sub` would ruin it.

Comment: `xor 0100000b` also works.

Comment: Thank you for the help. The input is established to be lowercase.

Comment: Those aren't ASCII single-quotes (or double quotes or backticks); NASM won't assemble that source.  Use `mov dx, 'a'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either one is acceptable, it's just a matter of preference. I like to use `and` myself. Shouldn't matter as long as you've checked to make sure your character is between `'a'` and `'z'` first.

Answer (score 3):

There's no performance or correctness difference if you already know the input is a lower-case alphabetic character.  `and` has the advantage when you know it's alphabetic but it might already be upper-case, since it leaves upper-case letters unmodified.  (Or as part of *detecting* alphabetic and normalizing to one case, either with `and` with `~0x20` or `or` with `0x20`, as in *[What is the idea behind ^= 32, that converts lowercase letters to upper and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54536362/what-is-the-idea-behind-32-that-converts-lowercase-letters-to-upper-and-vice/54585515#54585515)*)

---

If the next instruction is a `jcc` like `jnz`, `sub` and `and` are equally able to [macro-fuse with it into a single uop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56413517/what-is-instruction-fusion-in-contemporary-x86-processors) on Intel Sandybridge-family CPUs, so no advantage there.

If using it in a loop over a zero-terminated C string, you might be doing something like `movzx edx, byte [rdi]` / `and edx, ~0x20` / `jnz .loop` at the bottom of a loop, since all alphabetic characters have non-zero bits other than the lower-case bit.  (`0x20` is ASCII   space).

Using `sub` in that case lets you exit a loop on any character less than space, i.e. control characters, tabs, or newline.  `sub edx, 0x20` / `ja .loop`, or `jae .loop` to keep looping even on a space (but still not tab or newline).