# When using istruc in NASM: "warning: attempt to initialize memory in BSS section `.bss': ignored [-w+other]"

Tags: assembly, struct, compiler-errors, warnings, nasm

While searching for this error I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65731514/nasm-attempt-to-initialize-memory-in-bss-section/77001709) question, but was not exactly my issue. After a while I figured out the problem and posted another answer in that question, but following the advice of @ecm, I decided to make a different question.

My problem was that some time ago I declared a nasm `struc` like this (*Note that there is no `.b`*):

```
struc ctx_t
    .next: resd 1
    .prev: resd 1
    .a:    resd 1
    .c:    resd 1
endstruc
```

And after some time I added a `.b` member:

```
struc ctx_t
    .next: resd 1
    .prev: resd 1
    .a:    resd 1
    .b:    resd 1
    .c:    resd 1
endstruc
```

But forgot to edit the actual use of the structure with `istruc` in another file:

```
section .bss
    first_ctx:
        istruc ctx_t
            at ctx_t.next, resd 1
            at ctx_t.prev, resd 1
            at ctx_t.a,    resd 1
            ; Missing b!
            at ctx_t.c,    resd 1
        iend
```

And the assembler was giving me these warnings (all on the `ctx_t.c` line):

```
src/file.asm:8: warning: attempt to initialize memory in BSS section `.bss': ignored [-w+other]
src/file.asm:8: warning: attempt to initialize memory in BSS section `.bss': ignored [-w+other]
src/file.asm:8: warning: attempt to initialize memory in BSS section `.bss': ignored [-w+other]
src/file.asm:8: warning: attempt to initialize memory in BSS section `.bss': ignored [-w+other]
```

Question: Why does this warning occur? Why four times? And how can it be avoided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the missing `at ctx_t.b, resd 1` fixed it, so I didn't think much of the errors until @ecm answered and explained why.

Turns out that by not reserving the bytes myself, the assembler declares a zero byte *N* times (size of the member): [Link](https://github.com/netwide-assembler/nasm/blob/a916e4127b2eaa3bf40bddf3de9b0ceefc0d98a4/macros/standard.mac#L107).

So in this case, because `.b` was a dword, it was declaring 4 bytes as 0 using `times 4 db 0`. Obviously, the `.bss` section is not the right place for declaring bytes (since it's a `nobits` section, unlike, for example, `.text` which is `progbits`).

The solution would be to either add the `resd` for the missing member, or move the `istruc` to a `progbits` section (and obviously replace the `resd`'s).

That's the reason why the compiler was not only giving a warning, but 4 (one for each `db 0`)

Answer (score 2):

Here are some more solutions. First, a test case that reproduces your original problem (in one file that can be assembled as is):

```
struc ctx_t
    .next: resd 1
    .prev: resd 1
    .a:    resd 1
    .b:    resd 1
    .c:    resd 1
endstruc

section .bss
    first_ctx:
        istruc ctx_t
            at ctx_t.next, resd 1
            at ctx_t.prev, resd 1
            at ctx_t.a,    resd 1
            ; Missing b!
            at ctx_t.c,    resd 1
        iend

    resb 16
```

---

Then, my first solution. We use separate multi-line macros (mmacros) specialised for use in `nobits` sections, named `bss_istruc` and friends. (The `bss_istruc` mmacro itself is just an exact copy of NASM's `istruc`, but it is consistent to define it along the other two mmacros here.) This is the only solution that requires changes to your code, not just adding some macros.

```
%imacro bss_istruc 1.nolist
    %push
        %define %$strucname %1
        %$strucstart:
%endmacro

%imacro bss_at 1-2+.nolist
    %defstr %$member %1
    %substr %$member1 %$member 1
    %ifidn %$member1, '.'
        resb (%$strucname%1-%$strucname)-($-%$strucstart)
    %else
        resb (%1-%$strucname)-($-%$strucstart)
    %endif
    %2
%endmacro

%imacro bss_iend 0.nolist
        resb %{$strucname}_size-($-%$strucstart)
    %pop
%endmacro


struc ctx_t
    .next: resd 1
    .prev: resd 1
    .a:    resd 1
    .b:    resd 1
    .c:    resd 1
endstruc

section .bss
    first_ctx:
        bss_istruc ctx_t
            bss_at ctx_t.next, resd 1
            bss_at ctx_t.prev, resd 1
            bss_at ctx_t.a,    resd 1
            ; Missing b!
            bss_at ctx_t.c,    resd 1
        bss_iend

    resb 16
```

---

Next, my second solution. We undefine NASM's original `istruc` and friends and replace them by mmacros that check for the `.bss` section, by name, and will use `resb 1` when it is detected, and otherwise `db 0`. Obviously, if you use `nobits` sections other than the one named `.bss`, you would have to modify the detection to make it work.

It also expects that the mmacros are only used after plain `section .bss` or `segment .bss` directives. If you want to specify section attributes (eg `follows=`, `align=`, etc), then you need to subsequently add another `section` directive that names only the section name without attributes. (This is good form anyway, as use of the `__SECT__` macro will warn if your last `section` directive included attributes.)

```
%unimacro istruc 1.nolist
%unimacro at 1-2+.nolist
%unimacro iend 0.nolist

%imacro istruc 1.nolist
    %push
        %define %$strucname %1
        %$strucstart:
 %ifidni __SECT__, [section .bss]
    %define %$reservespace resb 1
 %elifidni __SECT__, [segment .bss]
    %define %$reservespace resb 1
 %else
    %define %$reservespace db 0
 %endif
%endmacro

%imacro at 1-2+.nolist
    %defstr %$member %1
    %substr %$member1 %$member 1
    %ifidn %$member1, '.'
        times (%$strucname%1-%$strucname)-($-%$strucstart) %$reservespace
    %else
        times (%1-%$strucname)-($-%$strucstart) %$reservespace
    %endif
    %2
%endmacro

%imacro iend 0.nolist
        times %{$strucname}_size-($-%$strucstart) %$reservespace
    %pop
%endmacro


struc ctx_t
    .next: resd 1
    .prev: resd 1
    .a:    resd 1
    .b:    resd 1
    .c:    resd 1
endstruc

section .bss
    first_ctx:
        istruc ctx_t
            at ctx_t.next, resd 1
            at ctx_t.prev, resd 1
            at ctx_t.a,    resd 1
            ; Missing b!
            at ctx_t.c,    resd 1
        iend

    resb 16
```

---

Next, a solution that does **not work**. The idea is to replace the use of `db 0` in the mmacros by a macro that will expand to a number of `resb` directives. This does not work because `times` is an assembler directive, not a preprocessor directive, so the `db 0` is never evaluated as an mmacro. Reproduced here for posterity.

```
struc ctx_t
    .next: resd 1
    .prev: resd 1
    .a:    resd 1
    .b:    resd 1
    .c:    resd 1
endstruc

section .bss
    first_ctx:

%imacro resb_for_every 1-*.nolist
 %rep %0
  %ifstr %1
   %strlen %%length %1
    resb %%length
  %else
    resb 1
  %endif
  %rotate 1
 %endrep
%endmacro

%idefine db resb_for_every

        istruc ctx_t
            at ctx_t.next, resd 1
            at ctx_t.prev, resd 1
            at ctx_t.a,    resd 1
            ; Missing b!
            at ctx_t.c,    resd 1
        iend

%undef db

    resb 16
```

---

Next, a revision of the above which makes it work, by using **only** a single-line macro (smacro) definition for the `db`. This is a super hack solution, but it does work if you take care to only ever replace `db 0` using this trick. (**ETA**: Modified slightly to allow any `db` with a single number to work.)

```
struc ctx_t
    .next: resd 1
    .prev: resd 1
    .a:    resd 1
    .b:    resd 1
    .c:    resd 1
endstruc

section .bss
    first_ctx:

%idefine db resb 1 + 0 *

        istruc ctx_t
            at ctx_t.next, resd 1
            at ctx_t.prev, resd 1
            at ctx_t.a,    resd 1
            ; Missing b!
            at ctx_t.c,    resd 1
        iend

%undef db

    resb 16
```

---

Finally, another take on the non-working solution: Instead of the `db` directive, we replace the `times` directive by a special mmacro. This mmacro will check for a  `db 0` string at the end of its parameter, making it safer than the prior hack.

```
struc ctx_t
    .next: resd 1
    .prev: resd 1
    .a:    resd 1
    .b:    resd 1
    .c:    resd 1
endstruc

section .bss
    first_ctx:

%imacro times_resb 1+.nolist
 %defstr %%our_string %1
 %strlen %%our_string_length %%our_string
 %substr %%our_db_0 %%our_string %%our_string_length + 1 - 5,-1
 %ifidni %%our_db_0, " db 0"
  %substr %%our_number_string %%our_string 1,-6
  %deftok %%our_number_token %%our_number_string
    resb %%our_number_token
 %else
  %error Unexpected use of times_resb macro: %%our_string %%our_db_0
 %endif
%endmacro

%idefine times times_resb

        istruc ctx_t
            at ctx_t.next, resd 1
            at ctx_t.prev, resd 1
            at ctx_t.a,    resd 1
            ; Missing b!
            at ctx_t.c,    resd 1
        iend

%undef times

    resb 16
```

Comment: Very interesting. I thought `times` was a preprocessor directive.

Comment: @trxgnyp1 The corresponding construct for preprocessor looping is made using `%rep` and `%endrep` directives.